# how to echo the path of the script executed from another location?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script file, let's say `abc.sh`. The full path is `/home/path/to/script/abc.sh`. Now I am currently executing the script from `/path/to/current` by executing this command -
`sh /home/path/to/script/abc.sh`. I want this script to `echo` it's location. The output should be `/home/path/to/script`

Answer (score 2):

Use this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
current_location=$(pwd)
script_location=$(dirname $0)
if [ $script_location= '.' ]
then
 script_location="$current_location"
fi
echo $script_location
```

Comment: Actually, OP is looking for: pwd

Comment: @Cryptopat I think no, he can use pwd if he is running the script from the directory where the script is stored..it won't work in another location